# How to split a string and skip whitespace?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a string like `" This   is a test "`. I want to split the string by the space character. I do it like this:

```
puts " This   is a test ".strip.each(' ') {|s| puts s.strip}
```

The result is:

> This
>
> is
>   a
>   test
>   This   is a test

Why is there the last line `"This   is a test"`?
And I need, that if there are two or more space characters between two words, that this should not return a "row".

I only want to get the words splitted in a given string.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
irb(main):002:0> " This   is a test ".split
=> ["This", "is", "a", "test"]

irb(main):016:0* puts " This   is a test ".split
This
is
a
test
```

[str.split(pattern=$;, [limit]) => anArray](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803)

> If pattern is omitted, the value of $;
>   is used. If $; is nil (which is the
>   default), str is split on whitespace
>   as if ` ’ were specified.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
" This   is a test ".strip.each(' ') {|s| puts s.strip}
```

If you don't want the last "this is a test"

Because

```
irb>>> puts " This   is a test ".strip.each(' ') {}
This   is a test
```

Answer (score 1):

The first command "puts" will be *put* after the each-block is excecuted.
omit the first "puts" and you are done