# Ruby string into array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a string like this :

```
"John Godson Michael Meyer Ludovicio Sforza Cezar Borgia Alessandro Batista"
```

How to convert this string into an array of strings like

```
# ["John", "Godson", "Michael Meyer" (...)]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby - split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005148/ruby-split-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use String#split

```
"John Godson Michael Meyer Ludovicio Sforza Cezar Borgia Alessandro Batista".split
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's test case: according to the OP, `'Michael Meyer'` should be a *single* string.

Answer (score 1):

```
"John Godson Michael Meyer Ludovicio Sforza Cezar Borgia Alessandro Batista".split(' ')
#=> ["John", "Godson", "Michael", "Meyer", "Ludovicio", "Sforza", "Cezar", "Borgia", "Alessandro", "Batista"]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's test case: according to the OP, `'Michael Meyer'` should be a *single* string.