# How to split the first and the last element on a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'm trying to split a string in 2 parts: the first word and the last one.
I know I need to use the `.split` method but don't know how.

Comment: The downvote and votes to close are probably due to your wording.  I suggest you edit to just say you want to extract the first and last words from a string.  Also, this is a pure Ruby question, so I also suggest you remove the Rails tag.

Comment: "split a string in 2 parts: the first word and the last one" only makes sense if the string consists exactly of two words. But it is still unnatural. You should say: "the former word and the latter one."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string and skip whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005148/how-to-split-a-string-and-skip-whitespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
first, *_, last = "now is the time for all".split
first #=> "now"
last  #=> "all"
```